# Amplify multiple env

Tags: environment-variables, aws-amplify

I have two environments for my Amplify backend and two branches Git Dev and Prod. Dev contains the Amplify environment Dev and Prod contains Prod. How can I update the (amplify) prod environment with dev content

git checkout dev
amplify env add dev
git checkout prod
amplify pull envName dev (error no dev env)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've same problem. Two different branches used for two different environments. Example Qa and Staging. How to provide two set of environment variables for two environments. For both environments variable names are same but values will be different.